# Is every open subset of a manifold homeomorphic to some Euclidean space?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M^n$ be a connected topological manifold. Is every proper open subset of $M$ homeomorphic to some open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What examples did you consider before asking this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider a surface of genus $g>1$ and remove a point.

Comment: Actually, an open cylinder is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (an annulus).  But your first example works.